# JavaFX: How to overwrite button action in custom Dialog

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx

I work on desktop application based on JDK 8 and JavaFX.

I created custom dialog class with 2 buttons(finish and cancel). My goal is to return the list of strings added in dialog (after clicking finish button, dialog returns list. Cancel makes return empty list).

I have problem, beacause function showAndWait return type of button which I clicked ('ButtonType.FINISH' or 'ButtonType.CANCEL'). My goal is to override default action on finish and close button and I want to return list instead of return button type.

It's always possible to create custom buttons, however, it would be better to use those already provided by JavaFX.

In response, you can use any of the JVM languages (Java/Kotlin/Scala).

Code:

```
class MyDialog : Dialog<MutableList<String>>() {
  val listToReturn: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    
  init {
    val dialogPane: DialogPane = this.dialogPane

    dialogPane.buttonTypes.addAll(ButtonType.FINISH, ButtonType.CANCEL)
  }
}
```

```
val myDialog: MyDialog = MyDialog()

// here I got ButtonType ('ButtonType.FINISH' or 'ButtonType.CANCEL'), not list of string
myDialog.showAndWait().ifPresent { list -> println(list) }
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. for best chances to draw interesr I would suggest plain javafx :)

Comment: @kleopatra what I added is not enough? I focused on the essence od the problem and I wanted to remain concise. All I can add in this code is starting javafx app and creating Scene.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding this question but if the object type is MyDialog and not Dialog, why not just add another function? Something like getList() that runs showAndWait on itself then returns listToReturn/Null.

Comment: it's an option. However, I would prefer to override the cancel and finish buttons in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a result converter

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog<List<String>> {
    ArrayList<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    public MyDialog() {
        returnList.add("test 1");
        returnList.add("test 2");
        this.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.FINISH, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
           if (dialogButton == ButtonType.FINISH) {
               return returnList;
           }
           return new ArrayList<>();
        });
    }
}
```

and for the application side

```
public class main extends Application {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
        myDialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }
}
```